# jquery dialog box is unwilling to explode

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

As the headline tells, the hide: "explode" function is not working...

here is the code:

```
function alerter(text, title) {
    var random = Math.floor( Math.random() * (1000000) );
    $('body').append('<div id="' + random + '">' + text + '</div>');
    $('#' + random).dialog({
        minHeight: 100,
        modal: true,
        hide: "explode",
        resizable: false,
        title: title,
        close: function(event, ui) { 
            $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
        }
    });
}
```

the box is just disapearing when I hit the x - but I want it to explode...
what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work just fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/xsnTs/1/